# How to implement External Authentication with local claims in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, ws-federation

I am working on a mvc 5 application and have configured WS Federation to authenticate using an external IP. However based on the functionality of the application, the users's roles need to be managed by application itself. An administrator of the application will allow different level of access to the application from an admin area of the application.  and since i am working with ASP.NET Identity for the first time i am lost on how to move forward from here.

- Do I need to implement a custom ClaimsAuthenticationManager for this?
- Do I also need to implement a UserManager to create local list of users to be able to manage their Claims?

Any direction/help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can add external claims in your override of `CreateUserIdentityAsync`.

This will add just Roles from your Federated login:

```
public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var externalIdentity =
        await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    var localIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    foreach (var item in externalIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role))
        localIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Value));

    return localIdentity;
}
```